# Divs inside container fly over container on click

Tags: jquery, css

I have 4 divs in a container, like this

```
.container{
    width:500px;
    height:450px;
    margin:0 auto;
    border:1px solid blue;  
}
.box1{  
    background-color:#F00;
    width:350px;
    height:450px;
    float:left;
}

.box2{
    background-color:#0F0;
    width:150px;
    height:150px;
    float:right;    
}

<div class="container">
    <div class="box1"></div>
    <div class="box2"></div>
    <div class="box2"></div>
    <div class="box2"></div>
</div>
```

I would like on click (on container or any div), that all divs inside container fly, and go off the screen (like an explosion).
I can do the animation with jQuery, but i can't find how to put the divs outside the container.
Any idea ?

Comment: Well the first thing you need to do is work out the end coordinates for each DIV. Presumably you want one to go to the top left, one to the top right, etc. This, essentially, is your challenge.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `animate` function:

```
$(".container").click(function()
{
    $(".box1").animate({top: "-200px", left: "-400px" }, 1000);
    $(".box2").animate({top: "-300px", left:  "100px" }, 1000);
    $(".box3").animate({top: "-500px", left: "-200px" }, 1000);
    $(".box4").animate({top:  "100px", left: "-500px" }, 1000);
});
```

in which the `top` and `left` attributes can be anything you like, but keep one of them negative to let them go off screen.

You can also modify them to `bottom` and `right` to let them go off the other side off the screen, but you need a pretty high value (like 2000)

Comment: Doesn't seem to work, because boxes are IN the container, and the container doesn't move. 
At start, the container is centered on the page (so are the boxes), and on click, the boxes go outside the screen...

Comment: Think i got it, boxes have to be in "relative" position. Thanks anyway :)